# Get metadata of currently playing song in iTunes Radio using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaitem

How can i get the metadata of the currently playing song from iTunes Radio (or other streaming services) using Swift?

I tried `MPMediaPlayer.nowPlayingItem` but that only works for songs that are physically on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this functionality is not supported at the moment.